# overlapping issue when using the magnificent popup plug in for lightbox overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using the lighbtox overlay from http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ in my website. in that page there is a "lightbox gallery" example

I used that example in http://37.60.251.65/~esoluti3/maximo/newseventsx.php. I copied the source code of the example exactly as it is

The problem is if you click on a small thumbnail then the enlarged image is coming under the main menu (it is overlapping and the main menu is covering the picture)

How do i fix this issue? i need the enlarged image to come on top of the main menu (picture covers main menu and not main menu cover image)

I also need the light grey overlay which shows when thumbnail is clicked to come on top of the main menu and not under it

I am using a readymade layout to make my website and i think the style rules of the layout are conflicting with the lightbox overlay. the logo of site and main menu are in a header tag. if i remove that tag then the lightbox overlay works perfectly

Also in the website that has the original example when you hover over a thumbnail the mouse icon will change to a magnifying glass with a + in it

In my website if you hover over a thumbnail the finger icon shows and not the magnifying glass with a + in it. if you click on a thumbnail and the enlarged image shows the icon will change to a magnifying glass with a - in it

I need the magnifying glass with a + in it to show in my website if you hover over the thumbnail. how do i fix this issue?

Comment: Change the z-index of your `<nav>` to something lower than that the lightbox has.

Answer (score 0):

There is mistakes in z-index

Lookout this property in your `css` file

```
header {
    background: url(../images/body-bg.png) repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: box-shadow:0 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: box-shadow:0 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -o-box-shadow: box-shadow:0 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    color: #bec9d5;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Replace your z-index with `100`

Like `z-index: 100;`

[Look this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nden.jpg)

**EDIT**

Add this 3 new properties in your css

```
.mfp-figure button.mfp-close {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.popup-gallery a {
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
    cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
    cursor: zoom-in;
}
.mfp-figure figure {
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
    cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
    cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: thanks :) this solved the issue

what about the other issue of the magnifying glass with + when i hover over thumbnail?

Comment: In http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ if you hover over a thumbnail the mouse icon will change to a magnifying glass. That is not happening in my page and when you hover over a thumbnail the mouse icon  changes into a finger and not a magnifying glass. I need it to change to a magnifying glass in my page also

Comment: @shadishtaklef i just update my answer please check it.. and if it is helpful to you than please accept my answer too. it will also helpful to me. :)

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but I didnt understand what u said

Comment: Just add this in your css it a new classes.. add that new classes

Comment: In the original example a magnifying glass with a + in it is showing when you hover over the small thumbnail. When you click on thumbnail and it expanded a magnifying glass with - in it shows when you want to close the enlarged image. For me the magnifying glass with a + in it is not showing and only the magnifying glass with - in it is showing when the enlarged image is opened. Did you understand my issue?